# Sending a large JavaScript object or large JSON value from the web server to the browser along with an HTML page response

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

**Background**

The browser requests my web server for a web page.

The web server returns an HTML page. It actually returns an ASP.NET MVC View decorated using a model. This is then flushed out as an HTML response. The usual stuff.

**What I want to make happen**

I'd like the web server to send a pretty large JavaScript object also along with the HTML response. And I am wondering how I could do that.

**Why**

1. *Just don't send it and let the client make an ajax request for the object later.*

   Basically, I am trying to avoid the cost of the client making an extra HTTP request to my web server to get that large object.
2. *Do the usual thing, decorate the view with the object at the server already. No need for any ajax call.*

   And I don't want to just decorate the UI with that object while preparing the ASP.NET MVC View because the client/browser has to do many things to the object before rendering it, so I'd like the client/browser to have full control over rendering the object on the UI.

I could stuff the stringified object, i.e. its JSON into a hidden input field, but I am not sure if that's going to work without any errors. I was wondering if there was a proper way to do this?

I am using ASP.NET MVC 5.2.4 targeting the .NET Framework 4.6.1.

Comment: IMO, using a script tag, and using the [defer](https://flaviocopes.com/javascript-async-defer/) attribute would probably be the best way. Yes it's another request, but it would be making it while your webpage is loading/rendering your DOM. The only other way is to include it near the end of your webpage (Right before `</body>`, which depending on the size of the object, would still have some performance impact on the DOM)

Comment: @FrankerZ Thank you. Re: your suggestion about *the only other way*, how would I include the object at the end of the page?

Comment: Well, I shouldn't say **only** other way, but to add it to the page, would be adding a `<script>` element, and just echoing out the JSON value to the page. ie. `<script>var bigJsonObject = <% AspNet.JsonObject %>;</script>`

Comment: I think this is a trade off, if the big object is not critical, better to load it with ajax, so your HTML can load faster... if the big object is critical (i.e. the user cannot use the page without the big object) then it's better to include it in the view... I think it is the same concept as bundling, which aims to download multiple resources together to improve the performance.